# cocos2dx C++ how to draw line with mousetouch (paint elements)

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Hello, everyone!

I'm a begginer at cocos and I want to draw the line with mousemove event. How can I do it?

I found a low of information on iOS language. But I want to see it on C++.

```
//HelloWorldScene.cpp
void HelloWorld::onTouchMoved(Touch* touches, Event* event)
{
    cocos2d::log("touch moved"); 
    // !!! 
    // What chould me add here?    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new circle sprite inside the touch moved function
there's a lot of ways to do that, but this will a good start for you.